# Is there a limit for the subdomains created on microsites?

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites, sender-authentication-package

I'm creating a Microsite in Marketing Cloud using the URL from the sender authentication package purchased for the business unit, and I can see something like:

> **http://myurl.com/[subdomain_to_be_added]**

Is there any limit for those subdomains or I can create an unlimited amount of Microsites with their respective subdomains?
Example:

- http://myurl.com/Microsite1
- http://myurl.com/Microsite2
- http://myurl.com/Microsite3

Comment: These are all part of a single domain. They are not subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many as you’d like but those aren’t sub domains.

http://thisisasubdomain.yoururl.com